# selenium send key not work

Tags: python, html, selenium

`elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` not work in my code. I used fined element by css selecter, thats my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
usr = raw_input('--> ')
pwd = raw_input('--> ')
poo = raw_input('--> ')
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/425526894264279/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# or you can use Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
assert "Facebook" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.send_keys(usr)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".input.textInput")
elem.send_keys(poo)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".selected")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a backward compatibility issue to me Just disabling all the `raw_input` worked for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
# usr = raw_input('---')
# pwd = raw_input('--> ')
# poo = raw_input('--> ')
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/425526894264279/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# or you can use Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
assert "Facebook" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.send_keys("NA")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elem.send_keys("NA")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".input.textInput")
elem.send_keys(poo)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".selected")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem.click()
```

I am using `3.4.1`

Comment: i mean elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem.click()
in the last lines

Comment: you mean it post in groups with you ? and whats your browser ?

Comment: I am on windows 8 and firefox

Comment: whats your firefox version ?

Comment: @elsharkawey I see can you clarify what is `elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".input.textInput")` doing?

Comment: its post text in facebook group